# jquery-textcomplete not working with Unicode characters, and missing space

Tags: javascript, jquery, unicode

**1.** I'm trying to use jquery-textcomplete with a Unicode string array. When I type an English word, it works properly, but no Unicode words are suggested. I think the problem is with the *'term'*. Check the below code and please help me:

```
var words = ['සහන', 'වනක', 'google', 'suresh namal',  'facebook', 'github', 'microsoft', 'yahoo', 'stackoverflow'];

$('textarea').textcomplete([{
    match: /(^|\s)(\w{2,})$/,
    search: function (term, callback) {
        callback($.map(words, function (word) {
            return word.indexOf(term) === 0 ? word : null;
        }));
    },
    replace: function (word) {
        return word + ' ';
    }
}]);
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/namaljayathunga/pbauw4y1/7)

**2.** Also, there is a problem with the return key. When I type *'google'* after *'stackoverflow'* it appears like *'stackoverflowgoogle'*. There is no space between *'stackoverflow'* and *'google'*. How can I solve that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The problem is with your `match` option, where only the latin words are matched (`\w`)

   > `\w` matches any alphanumeric character including the underscore. Equivalent to [A-Za-z0-9_].

   [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-word)

   You should also include unicode characters in your RegExp, like: `\u0000-\u007f`

---

2. this is because of using `\s` (notice small "s") in your RegExp, which also replaces a 'space' preceding the keyword:

   > `\s` matches a single white space character, **including** space (...)

   [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-white-space)

   You could use there `\S` (capital "S") which matches a single character **other than** space, along with a `*` (asterisk) which matches the preceding space 0 or more times.

---

It's probably not a prettiest RegExp, but should do the job for you:

```
$('textarea').textcomplete([{
    match: /(^|\S*)([^\u0000-\u007f]{2,}|\w{2,})$/,
    search: function (term, callback) {
        callback($.map(words, function (word) {
            return word.indexOf(term) > -1 ? word : null;
        }));
    },
    replace: function (word) {
        return word+' ';
    }
}]);
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mqxv8vn3/)

Comment: Thanks so much Artur Flipiak. You had described it clearly. Thanks

Comment: can you help me. Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30221748/jquery-textcomplete-not-work-on-contenteditable-div). Thanks.