# jQuery-textcomplete does not work on contenteditable div from Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension, jquery-autocomplete

I am working on simple auto complete chrome extension using [jQuery-textcomplete](https://github.com/yuku-t/jquery-textcomplete) script.

It is working well on most of traditional sites, because they use textarea. It is not working on Google+ comment box, Facebook comment box and even gmail.

Because they only use div tag with HTML5 'contenteditable' option to get user's text, and also use react in facebook.

So jquery selector not working. How can I solve this problem? Here is my selector.

```
$("textarea, .editable, textbox, text").textcomplete([{
    match: /(^|\S*)([^\u0000-\u007f]{2,}|\w{2,})$/,
    search: function (term, callback) {
    callback($.map(EnDict, function (word) {
        return word.indexOf(uni_word) === 0 ? word : null;
    }));
    },
    replace: function (word) {
     return word + ' ';
   }
}]);
```

[There is Github Repository](https://github.com/namaljayathunga/jquery-textcomplete--chrome-extension)

[image]

Comment: It seems this feature request has been posted here already: https://github.com/yuku-t/jquery-textcomplete/pull/38

Comment: yes actualy it's working well on contenteditable div. However it is not support or some problem with Google+ comment box and Facebook comment box.

Comment: I found it not support to the contentediable div on Chrome extension.