# Why do UTF-8 characters not work in jquery textcomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, utf-8, autocomplete, cyrillic

I am using the autocompleter [jquery-textcomplete](https://github.com/yuku-t/jquery-textcomplete) in my web app. It's working fine for English and Russian letters. But it is not working for certain special letters such as **"ҷ"**.

Code:

```js
$('.form-control').textcomplete([{
  words: ['тоҷик', 'ҷаҳон', 'english'],
  match: /(^|[^\wа-яёҷ])([\wа-яё]{2,})$/i,
  search: function(term, callback) {
    callback($.map(this.words, function(word) {
      return word.indexOf(term) === 0 ? word : null;
    }));
  },
  index: 2,
  replace: function(word) {
    return '$1' + word + ' ';
  }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.textcomplete/1.8.4/jquery.textcomplete.min.js"></script>

<textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
```

Here the words `'тоҷик'` and `'english'` are working but `'ҷаҳон'` is not. How can I fix this?

I need the following letters to work: `ғ,ӯ,қ,ҳ,ҷ,ӣ` and `а-я`.

Comment: Could you try, from what you have, to narrow it to single characters that are not working... Instead of words?

Comment: List of special letters ғ,ӯ,қ,ҳ,ҷ,ӣ @Louys Patrice Bessette

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29124968/jquery-textcomplete-not-work-with-unicode-and-remove-space) was already answered.

```js
$('#textcomplete').textcomplete([{
  words: ['тоҷик', 'ҷаҳон', 'english'],
  match: /(^|\S*)([^\u0000-\u007f]{2,}|\w{2,})$/,
  search: function(term, callback) {
    callback($.map(this.words, function(word) {
      return word.indexOf(term) === 0 ? word : null;
    }));
  },
  index: 2,
  replace: function(word) {
    return word + ' ';
  }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.textcomplete/1.8.4/jquery.textcomplete.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="textcomplete"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I use textcomplete because in the autocomplete after writing the first word the second time the list of words does not appear. Maybe it's possible to solve this problem but I have not tried it yet. @bigless

Comment: @John yea I already removed that stupid question and irrelevant code. I got it. textcomplete is for textarea while autocomplete(without tweaking) for inputs.

Comment: Ok, Thanks! Please comment this code for me if you can: `/(^|\S*)([^\u0000-\u007f]{2,}|\w{2,})$/` @bigless

Comment: @John this regex is already described in link I provided at beginning.

Comment: That's all, I understood your code. Thank you for the answer  @bigless